# React Native Component Without UI

Tags: swift, react-native

I would like to create a React Native Component without using the `render()` method.

Basically what I want to do is writing a service lets called it `Calculator` with a function `addUp(num:number, plus:number)`

```
class Caluclator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    addUp(num:number, plus:number) {
        return num + plus 
    }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Caluclator', () => Caluclator);
```

Now when I try to call this function from Native

```
bridge?.enqueueJSCall("Caluclator", method: "addUp", args: [], completion: {
            print("DONE")
        })
```

I get the error

> Unhandled JS Exception: Module Caluclator is not a registered
>   callable module (calling addUp)

Any idea or solution or even an example?

Note: I do not want to use `RCTRootView`

Answer (score -1):

you can always `return null` in your render() method.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use [native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) instead of component and then in native code just call native module methods.

Comment: The question is about using a React Native component from native code, not the other way around which is what Native Modules are about